# Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread

Tags: swift, http, dispatch-queue

I'm having an issue with a Swift function. I have my class which manages all the networking, and in there I have two functions: fetchData, which gets an array of IDs, and getPosts, which gets all posts related to those IDs via a DispatchGroup and appends them to a published array, which I will then use in the View.

The issue I'm facing is:

`Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.`.

The published variable assignment is already wrapped in a DispatchQueue.main.async block. What am I missing?

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    var feedPosts: [Int] = []
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    func fetchData(feedType: PostsOrderType) -> Void {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/\(feedType)stories.json") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if (error == nil){
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let result = data {
                        do {
                            let decodedRes = try decoder.decode([Int].self, from: result)
                            self.feedPosts = decodedRes
                            self.getPosts()
                        }   catch {
                            print("Decoding error: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }   else {
                    print("Error retrieving data: \(error!)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    
    func getPosts() -> Void {
        
        let dGroup = DispatchGroup()
        //Limited to 15 to reduce networking times
        let firstTenResults = self.feedPosts[0...15]
        
        for id in firstTenResults{
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(id).json")
            else {
                return
            }
            
            dGroup.enter()
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
                data, response, error in
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let result = data {
                    do {
                        let decodedRes = try decoder.decode(Post.self, from: result)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.posts.append(decodedRes)
                        }
                    }   catch {
                        print("Error decoding data: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                dGroup.leave()
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is not from `self.feedPosts = decodedRes`?

Comment: ```self.feedPosts = decodedRes``` is just the array of post IDs, it won't get published. I tried wrapping that one inside a DispatchQueue block as well, but no luck.

Comment: `for id in firstTenResults` will iterate over 15 posts: your code might be trying to update the second feed while the first feed is still updating the UI. You may want to store the results in an array and then update the `@Published var posts` only once.

Comment: I see, thanks. By the way, the warning disappeared on its own for no apparent reason. Figures.